# How to cancel an Outlook.MailItem changes?

Tags: outlook, ms-office, add-in, mailitem

I am doing changes on an Outlook.MailItem but after closing the last explorer a message box asks to save the item (twice!).

I want to cancel the "dirty" state of the item without saving it so no message box will be displayed.

Is it possible to accomplish it? The only solution that I have is persisting the previous state and saving it again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to release COM objects, created in your code. See [When to release COM objects in Office add-ins developed in .NET](http://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2008/10/30/releasing-office-objects-net/).